# Is there a way to make the repository call run pararell?

Tags: spring-boot, project-reactor

In my project, I'm running multiple queries at the same time. Here is the example of what im currently doing

In my repository I'm doing something like this
"select count(columnName) from tableName"

columnName and tableName are variables which Im passing from the service. Lets say I have 100+ columns that needs to be counted, then I have to call the select query 100+ times which is time consuming. Is it possible to run this in parallel or at least by batch?

Already tried the reactor core and used flux but looks like its still running sequential. I have read that jdbc is blocking which is why it needs to wait for the other query to finish before it executes another. But is it always the case or is there other way.

I'm using spring boot and jdbc for this.

Edit:
So far this is my current implementation

```
List<Mono<Count>> countMonoList = new ArrayList<>();
countList.forEach(c -> {
  Mono<Count> blockingWrapper = Mono.fromCallable(() -> countRepo.selectQuery(c));
blockingWrapper = blockingWrapper.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
blockingWrapper.subscribe();
countMonoList.add(blockingWrapper);
});
```

Then I need to convert the `List<Mono<Count>>` into `List<Count>` for the next process. Right now Im getting db connection failed after running some few queries.

Edit again:
Looks like connection pool has limit. Tried to limit the countList to 15 and did not receive db connection failed

Answer (score 0):

This will run in parallel up to the number of connections in the pool.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;

import com.example.demo.count.CountingService;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Springboot3Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springboot3Application.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    CountingService countingService;

    @EventListener
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        List<String[]> tableInfo = Arrays.asList(new String[][] {new String[] {"countries", "id"}, new String[] {"countries", "name"}});

        List<String[]> results = tableInfo.parallelStream().map(entry -> {
            int count = countingService.count(entry[0], entry[1]);
            return new String[] { entry[0], entry[1], count + "" };
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

}
```

**CountingService**

```
public interface CountingService {

    int count(String tableName, String tableColumn);

}
```

**CountingServiceImpl**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class CountingServiceImpl implements CountingService {
    
    @Autowired 
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public int count(String tableName, String columnName) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "select count(" + columnName + ") from " + tableName, Integer.class);
    }
    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reactor provides 2 api's to convert a blocking sync calls to no blocking via
[Mono.fromCallable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromCallable-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) and [Mono.fromRunnable](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromRunnable-java.lang.Runnable-)

If multiple calls need to happen parallelly then you can offload this to a Schedular (can choose bounded elastic for IO based work)

Can look [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking) and [here](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#schedulers) more for details. Below is a hacked up sample for reference

```
private static void computeFromCallable() {
    for (int i = 0; i<200; i++){
        Mono<Integer> integerMono = Mono
                .fromCallable(MTSample::compute)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
        integerMono
                .subscribe((x) -> System.out.println("return value for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is: " + x));
    }
}

static Random rand1 = new Random();
private static int compute() throws InterruptedException {
    int i = rand1.nextInt(2000);
    int j = rand1.nextInt(10);
    System.out.println("sleep delay for thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is: " + i);
    Thread.sleep(i);
    return j;
}
```

Comment: I need to compile all the mono in a list then block once all are complete. Is that possible?